# How to generate allure report with calabash?

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android, allure

I'm using calabash for automate mobile app.
Is it possible to integrate allure report in calabash framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create report for calabash test:

Install allure for cucumber:

- `gem install allure-cucumber`

Then add following into features/support/env.rb file

```
require 'allure-cucumber'
AllureCucumber.configure do |c|
   c.output_dir = "reports"
end
```

Above i have given "reports" as folder name, so the report of test will reside here.

Now run the calabash test:

- `calabash-android run 'your.apk' --format AllureCucumber::Formatter`

This much will create an XML file as result in "reports" folder.

You can do more customization on test go through [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cucumber)

Comment: rubocop wil flag your code; you can be a lot more succinct like this:


`AllureCucumber.configure { |c| c.output_dir = 'reports' }`

Answer (score 1):

I currently use Allure for my reporting.

Their [Readme](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cucumber) has the step by step process.

TL;DR

- Add `gem 'allure-cucumber'` to your gemfile
- Bundle install
- Add `require 'allure-cucumber'` to your env file
- Add `AllureCucumber.configure do |config|
  config.output_dir = 'allure'
  end`
  to your env.rb file -

*note: you can change the location of your reports. I use a folder called allure*

- Then add `--format AllureCucumber::Formatter` to your cucumber profile or runner options

*note: depending on what formatters you are using you may have to throw in a fake --out location for allure. To resolve this I just do `--format AllureCucumber::Formatter --out temp.html`*

After this you can generate the report using their [command line tool](http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Commandline)

Hope this helps

Comment: Happy to help! Even though this post is pretty old :D